# EditText for typing a license

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

On my android app, first time when app runs, user must type a license. The license's format is `###-XXX-###-###` where `#` is a number, `X` is a character. I put the format as hint but it is not sufficient. How can I make like this and user does not enter -, it just appear after 3 characters ?

UPDATE :

That's my code and it works :

```
licenseEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                System.out.println("afterTextChanged");
                if (s.length() == 3) {
                    s.append("-");
                }
                if (s.length() == 7) {
                    s.append("-");
                }
                if (s.length() == 11) {
                    s.append("-");
                }
                if (s.length() == 15)
                    ok.performClick();
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                System.out.println("beforeTextChanged");
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                System.out.println("onTextChanges");

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set a `TextWatcher` , inside it compare intered text with a `regularExpression` . and put other code like after first 3 charachets append "-" to intered characterSet .

Comment: @Shailendra an example would be helpfull :)

Comment: its my own thought, so cant navigate you to any url . and i never appreciate to writing entire code for others . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use 4 EditTexts and attach textwathers to them - a windows-like license input

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the % operator

```
if( s.length() == 15) {
   // s.length() = 15
} else if( s.length() % 4 == 3) {
   // s.length = {3, 7, 11, 19, ....}
   // so s.length != 15
}
```

In this way you have less code duplication. For more information check: [Wikipedia - Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)